# how to find and replace in csv using python

Tags: python, csv, file-read

I have csv file with 900 rows and 11 columns. It contains approximately 4000 links which I want to replace with 4000 links (I have another csv file which contains both links in column 1 and 2). 
I am trying to automate it (find and replace) using python 
Here is my code but it is not working. Actually I am not getting any error but program run continuously without giving any results. I run it for 2. 3 hours and helplessly killed it.

```
import csv 
def replace_all(text, dic):
  for i, j in dic.iteritems():
   text = text.replace(i, j)
 return text

with open('file_that_find_replace_data.csv', mode='r') as infile:
 reader = csv.reader(infile)
 d = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}

f = open('main_file.csv','r') 
filedata = f.read() 
for row in filedata:
  newdata = replace_all(filedata, d)

f = open('main_file.csv','w') 
f.write(newdata) 
f.close()
print ('done')
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: (I didn't downvote, but that's why you were downvoted)

Comment: Why aren't you using the `csv` module for reading `main.csv`?

Comment: "It is not working" may be an accurate description but we need some more information that that.

Comment: @coldspeed actually code is running for more than two hours without giving any results and helplessly I have to kill program

Comment: Right, but you can still debug. Add some print() functions. Does d contain what you expect? A print inside each loop will tell you where it is getting stuck. Same for newdata. Or paste it in section-by-section in an interactive python shell, or IPython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself 
Thanks all for help

```
import csv
findd=[]
repl=[]
with open('find_replace_data.csv', mode='r') as infile:
  reader = csv.reader(infile)
  for rows in reader:
      a= rows[0]
      b= rows[1]
      findd.append(a)
      repl.append(b)



ifile = open('infile.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(ifile)
ofile = open('outfile.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(ofile)

rep = dict(zip(findd, repl))

s = ifile.read()
for item in findd:
    s = s.replace(item, rep[item])
ofile.write(s)
ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in filedata:
  newdata = replace_all(filedata, d)
```

This will leave you with only the last line of the file in `newdata`. Maybe `newdata +=` instead? Or write the output lines within the loop. But also, why not use csvfile for both files?